# OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/ no such table: main.auth_user__old

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-errors

I was editing a project on Django, so I deleted my *pychache*, *migrations*, and *db.sqlite3* and created a new **superuser** to log into the admin page. After I created a product and pressed 'Save' on the admin page an error saying "OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/ no such table: main.auth_user__old" appeared. I have tried solving this issue with solutions such as reinstalling Django 2.0.7 and doing **makemigrations** and **migrate** again, but none of the solutions I have tried have worked so far. Does anyone know of a possible solution to this?

Comment: can I see you models.py file.

Comment: This is my models.py file `from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
 title   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
 description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
 price   = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
 summary  = models.TextField()`

Comment: try upgrading you django  'pip install Django --upgrade' and re-migrate everything.

Comment: Just did that and now when I click on the Products part on the Django Admin site I immediately get a new error message saying ***TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/products/product/
Invalid block tag on line 45: 'change_list_object_tools', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?***

Comment: You should have {% not { %, and you got those typos in templates or you forgot to end the block. check you template properly

Comment: My line 45 has this in the problem screen ***45   {% change_list_object_tools %}***

Comment: what is this for? extending template, including template

Comment: I was trying to re-edit my models.py (essentially changing it because I wanted to use different model fields) and change its then-existing database, so I deleted my *pychache*, *migrations*, and *db.sqlite3* and created a new **superuser** to log into the admin page.

Comment: did you delete the __init__.py file as well from migration folder.

Comment: No, the ***__init__.py*** and the ***migration*** folder itself were among the things that I didn't delete, but I did delete the ***__pycache__*** folder

Comment: So, the problem right now is with the template. is this (change_list_object_tools) a context object

Comment: The ***change_list_object_tools*** is part of the code in the Traceback for the file in /admin/products/product/

Comment: i mean did you define it somewhere in your template if soo can i see that template code where you define it

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Upgrade to latest Django version (at least 3.1.7)

Steps to fix:

- Stopped the django webserver running, Ctrl-C
- Delete the `db.sqlite3`
- Uninstalled Django old verison
- Install latest version of Django with `pip install django` or this latest version 3.1.7
- Issue `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Issue `python manage.py migrate`
- Create a superuser with `python manage.py createsuperuser`
- Issue `python manage.py runserver` (or port 8080)
- Navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`
- You will successfully able to add table manually.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for error is when you forget to migrate after you have created a superuser. Migrating as soon as I create the superuser solves my problem. Run the following commands:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

You should see the ok status on the following operations:

```
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, {APP_NAME}
```

Open your shell or admin admin and try to add that product again.

Answer (score 0):

- copy all models code to outer txt file.
- Delete the whole app that contains models issue.
  and make sure to remove app name from setting's app.
  and main urls.
- create a new app with different name.
- add new app name to setting's apps.
- move the code form the txt file to models file
- run 'makemigrations' & 'migrate' respectively.
- runserver.