# OperationalError at /admin/myforms/uploadedfile/add/ while adding data to Table using django admin

Tags: django, file-upload

I have got a problem while adding data to table using django admin , I am clearly new to django concept and i don know what mistake i did .

it says "OperationalError at /admin/myforms/uploadedfile/add/ " while adding data to table manually . and says the table doesn't exist . But while migrating it shows the table name as uploadedfiles . I just want to add data manually and save it inside django admin .

so screenshots attached
[image: Table Django Admin]
[image: Adding Value]
[image: Error]

I deleted all the migration files inside Migration , and tried performing in the way as shown in [OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/ no such table: main.auth_user__old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62421906/operationalerror-at-admin-products-product-add-no-such-table-main-auth-user)

but after i performed all the operation still am getting the same error , and my migration folder is empty .

here is my models.py

```
class Uploadedfile(models.Model):
    def file_path(self, filename):
        return f'uploaded_files/{self.server}/{self.path.replace(":", "$", 1)}/{filename}'

    files_to_upload = models.FileField(
        upload_to=file_path,
        default=None,
        validators=[validate_file]
    )
    
    
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    server = MultiSelectField(choices=server_list)
```

Can anyone of you help me solve this issue .

Answer (score 1):

you can try by flush the database i hopes it will help you .
if you have important data in db you can dump data .
`python manage.py flush`
`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: sorry am not getting it

Comment: it still says table is not thr